# trouble in mkdir with Chinese characters on window + xampp

Tags: php, encoding, mkdir

I am trying to create a folder with name `测试` on xampp installed on my windows computer.

```
$new    =   "测试";
mkdir("test/$new");
```

It creates folder but the folder name is `æµ‹è¯•` not `测试`.

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$new    =   mb_convert_encoding("测试", 'CP936', 'UTF-8');
mkdir("test/".$new,0777);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$new    =   "测试";
mkdir("test/".$new,0777);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$new    =   urlencode ("测试");
mkdir("test/".$new,0777);
```

and use urldecode if you want original name;

Comment: not solve my purpose.. unable to load it on browser.. like http://127.0.0.1/test/%E6%B5%8B%E8%AF%95, it gives 404.

Comment: do u using UTF8 encoding?  changed to GB2312 and see. And check the path of directory too properly once. urlencode should work