# trouble in mkdir with japanese characters on window + xampp

Tags: php, encoding, mkdir

I am having a problem creating a folder with Japanese name using the `mkdir()` function in PHP. The problem is about folder displays weird character as picture shown:

[image]

I have checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38789788/trouble-in-mkdir-with-chinese-characters-on-window-xampp) and have tried to use `mb_convert_string` function but it did not work.

I also tried to use iconv function as suggested by [rodrigo at bb2 dot co dot jp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)  but it's still not working. The following is my code:

```
$yugioh    =  iconv('UTF-8', 'SJIS', 'マリク・イシュタール');
mkdir("yugioh/".$yugioh,0777);
```

Comment: It looks like your defined language in windows is some form of chinese that's not UTF-based. In this case you simply cannot mix and match languages.

Comment: Based on [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38789788/trouble-in-mkdir-with-chinese-characters-on-window-xampp], chinese name folder is worked for me but japanese name folder did not work for me. So,should I change the default charset on window?

Comment: No, because then any files you have named in Chinese will be broken. The only possible way to have  Chinese _and_ Japanese filenames would be to reinstall windows, specify a UTF charset, and then convert all of your existing filenames from cp932 to whichever flavor of UTF you went with.

Comment: I want to change folder name only. Is any possible way to solve it instead of reinstall windows?